# Can you place a fullscreen YouTube video in one monitor and search in the other?

Tags: multiple-monitors, video, flash, vlc, youtube

All right, I have two monitors and suddenly I feel the need to have a video playing (any kind but preferably YouTube videos) in one monitor while selecting what song is going to play next in other monitor:

The main goal is that in the "video monitor" the "search" for the next video doesn't appear at all.

How can I do this?

### P.S.:

When I say any kind of video I mean that it would be really cool if that can be done with any website (e.g. Vimeo, YouTube, Metacafe, sockshare <for movies>) or software (VLC or a presentations software {actually I've seen that Windows 8 [or the new Powerpoint, not sure here] has a cool feature where you can make presentations in a video beam and in your computer you can see what slide is next}).

Comment: If the monitor has hdmi you can hook up a chromecast

Comment: @Mateo Thanks for taking the time to have a look here and post a comment, unfortunately no, my monitor does not have HDMI it's VGA only.